# Randomize questions from web API and print out wrong answer

Tags: python, list

I want to get 10 random questions from an web API with many questions, but I dont seem to get it to work. Right now im getting **KeyError: 'prompt'**, but I dont know if the function is correct at all as I have been trying a few diffrent options.

Im also trying to print out in the end which questions you get wrong, but with no luck there either.

```
import random
import requests
from random import randint

url = ""
the_questions = requests.get(url).json()
print("------ Welcome to Python quiz ------")


def random_question():
    data = the_questions['prompt']
    random_index = randint(0, len(data)-1)
    return data[random_index]['prompt']


def get_correct_answers(answers):
    res = []
    for ans in answers:
        if ans['correct']:
            res.append(ans['answer'])
    return res


def get_numeric(prompt, max_value,):
    while True:
        try:
            res = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Answer only with a number!")
            continue
        if 0 < res < max_value:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid answer option!")
    return res


def main():
    score = 0
    for questions in the_questions['questions']:
        #print(questions['prompt'])
        print(random_question())

        for i, a in enumerate(questions['answers'], start=1):
            print(f"[{i}] {a['answer']}")
        user_answer = get_numeric("> ", len(questions['answers']) + 1)

        if questions['answers'][user_answer - 1]['correct']:
            score += 1
            print(f"Right!")
        else:
            all_correct = ", ".join(get_correct_answers(questions['answers']))
            print(f"Wrong, right is: {all_correct}")
    print(f"You got {score} points of {len(the_questions['questions'])} possible!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample of the API

```
{"questions":[{"id":"1","prompt":"Which functions is used to write out text in the terminal?","answers":[{"answer":"print","correct":true},{"answer":"input","correct":false},{"answer":"import","correct":false},{"answer":"sys.exit","correct":false}]}
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: FULL error should show you in which line you have problem and you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in this line. As for me all this has nothing to do directly with API. You only use data in wrong way.

Comment: first you use `data = the_questions['prompt']` and later you use `data[random_index]['prompt']` so finally you use `data = the_questions['prompt'][random_index]['prompt']` and you have `['promp']` two times - and this can be your problem. Probably you should remove second `['prompt']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows problem with key `prompt` and you use it only in `random_question()`.

If you use `print()` to see values in variables `random_question()` then you will see that you need

```
    data = the_questions['questions']
```

instead of

```
    data = the_questions['prompt']
```

---

As for me name of variables are missleading. You should use name `data` for all information from API and later `questions = data['questions']` could make sense.

---

**EDIT:**

My version with `random.shuffle()`

```
import random
#import requests
import json

def get_correct_answers(answers):
    res = []
    for ans in answers:
        if ans['correct']:
            res.append(ans['answer'])
    return res

def get_numeric(prompt, max_value,):
    while True:
        try:
            res = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Answer only with a number!")
            continue
        if 0 < res < max_value:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid answer option!")
    return res


def main():

    print("------ Welcome to Python quiz ------")
    
    #url = ""
    #data = requests.get(url).json()

    data = json.loads('''
{"questions":[
    {"id":"1","prompt":"Which functions is used to write out text in the terminal?","answers":[{"answer":"print","correct":true},{"answer":"input","correct":false},{"answer":"import","correct":false},{"answer":"sys.exit","correct":false}]},
    {"id":"2","prompt":"Which functions is used to read text from the terminal?","answers":[{"answer":"print","correct":false},{"answer":"input","correct":true},{"answer":"exec","correct":false},{"answer":"load","correct":false}]}
]}
''')

    questions = data['questions']
    random.shuffle(questions)
    
    score = 0
    
    for question in questions:
        
        print(question['prompt'])

        answers = question['answers']
        for i, a in enumerate(question['answers'], 1):
            print(f"[{i}] {a['answer']}")
            
        user_answer = get_numeric("> ", len(answers)+1)

        if answers[user_answer-1]['correct']:
            score += 1
            print(f"Right!")
        else:
            all_correct = ", ".join(get_correct_answers(answers))
            print(f"Wrong, right is: {all_correct}")
            
    print(f"You got {score} points of {len('questions')} possible!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. Have changed name on a few variables. I get random questions now, but the answer alternatives doesnt follow(they stay in the original position)

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page.

Comment: you may have problem because you use `random_question()` to select random question but later you use always the same `questions['answers']` to display answers. You should use `random_question` to get only `data[random_index]` instead of `data[random_index]['prompt']` and later use `['prompt']` to display question and `['answers']` to display answers. BTW: you chould use `random.shuffle` to shuffl questions at start and later use only `for`-loop to get next question - and then you should get every question only once. Using `random.randint` you may get the same question few times.

Comment: I added full working code with `random.shuffle()`

Comment: Thank you! Changed a few things but got it working now. Got me understanding the issue as well.